# How to install Oracle Java 8 using Ansible

Tags: java, ansible

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

This installer has 2 full screen prompts and ansible fails when trying to install this package.

```
- name: Add Oracle Java PPA
  apt_repository:
    repo: ppa:webupd8team/java
    state: present

- name: Install Java 8
  apt:
    name: oracle-java8-installer
    update_cache: yes
```

Comment: The playbooks which utilize WebUpd8team PPA no longer work after Oracle changed their licensing scheme. See the following notice on the [WebUpd8team PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java):

"Oracle Java downloads now require logging in to an Oracle account to download Java updates, like the latest Oracle Java 8u211 / Java SE 8u212. Because of this I cannot update the PPA with the latest Java (and the old links were broken by Oracle). For this reason, THIS PPA IS DISCONTINUED (unless I find some way around this limitation)."

Answer (score 17):

https://github.com/malk/ansible-java8-oracle

```
---
- name: Install add-apt-repostory
  become: yes
  apt: name=software-properties-common state=latest

- name: Add Oracle Java Repository
  become: yes
  apt_repository: repo='ppa:webupd8team/java'

- name: Accept Java 8 License
  become: yes
  debconf: name='oracle-java8-installer' question='shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1' value='true' vtype='select'

- name: Install Oracle Java 8
  become: yes
  apt: name={{item}} state=latest
  with_items:
    - oracle-java8-installer
    - ca-certificates
    - oracle-java8-set-default
```

Comment: Small addition: 'with_items' is replaced by 'loop' since 2.5 or so.[link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.5.html#with-items) Now i get a deprecation warning that it will be removed in 2.11

Comment: If you add just `oracle-java8-set-default` it will already add the `oracle-java8-installer` as dependency

Comment: No package matching 'oracle-java8-set-default' is available. I used `openjdk-8-jre-headless`