# Java installation issue using ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I am trying to install the java8 using ansible playbook. Below is the yml file of my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: test2
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: install the java pre-requisties
    apt:
      name: software-properties-common 
      state: latest
  - name: add oracle java repository
    apt_repository:
         repo: 'ppa:webupd8team/java'
  - name: update repository
    apt: 
      update_cache: yes
  - name: Accept Java 8 License
    debconf:
     name: 'oracle-java8-installer' 
     question: 'shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1' 
     value: true 
     vtype: 'select'
  - name: install java 8
    apt: 
     name: oracle-java8-installer 
     force: yes
```

But i am getting the below error:

`fatal: [host2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "No package matching 'oracle-java8-installer' is available"}`

Can you please help me to fix the issue?

Any assistance will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Oracle Java 8 using Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50536756/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-using-ansible)

Comment: I have tried that playbook also and getting same error.

Comment: Did you try to check what is available on the server?

Comment: You're going to have to give us more output, as that one line is the _result_ of several other lines failing in some way. Also, watch out that `value: true` will attempt to send a boolean to `debconf` whereas you likely want `value: "true"` to transmit the letters t-r-u-e to debconf

Comment: @AHT, Yes i have checked at the server and when i tried to install manually the package oracle-java8-installer using apt command its installed.

Comment: Can you try `force_apt_get: yes` instead of `force: yes`?

Comment: @AHT, Thanks force_apt-get works for me.

Comment: Glad to hear that

Answer (score 0):

Possible Network issue with server reaching Repository, Please check locally using apt commands if package can be download.

Comment: Yes, i have checked via run the command locally using apt command and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing deb_oracle_package: 'oracle-java8-installer' to deb_oracle_package: 'openjdk-8-jre-headless' in my mains.yml for ansible.