# How to Install Java 8 Using Ansible Without PPA

Tags: java, java-8, ansible

I normally would install Java 8 with Ansible with the following code:

```
---
- name: Install add-apt-repostory
  become: yes
  apt: name=software-properties-common state=latest

- name: Add Oracle Java Repository
  become: yes
  apt_repository: repo='ppa:webupd8team/java'

- name: Accept Java 8 License
  become: yes
  debconf: name='oracle-java8-installer' question='shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1' value='true' vtype='select'

- name: Install Oracle Java 8
  become: yes
  apt: name={{item}} state=latest
  with_items:
    - oracle-java8-installer
    - ca-certificates
    - oracle-java8-set-default
```

Ref. the following stacked overflow question for original author.

[How to install Oracle Java 8 using Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50536756/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-using-ansible)

However, since  the Oracle JDK License has changed for releases on April 16, 2019. This PPA has been discontinued and my ansible code now returns the following error when attempting to install Java 8...

> Package oracle-java8-installer is not available, but is referred to by
>   another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate

Does anyone know how to automate the installation of Java 8 with Ansible now that the PPA has been discontinued and the Oracle Licences have changed?

Comment: Define "install". Carry out the same steps as the PKG? Unpack the PKG and copy the steps. Something else? You'll need to define what that is...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Either carry out the same steps as the PKG or literally download the file from the Java website, unpack the file and install the executable. I.e. whatever is necessary for Java 8 to be operational on the operating system and be callable from the command line interface.

Comment: The PKG goes via the alternatives mechanism, i would recommend simply unzipping it and looking through the scripts (a `.deb` is simply an archive).

Comment: May be you can use open jdk in the ansible task which you can easily find in Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I sign up for oracle account then download the .rpm/.tar.gz package directly from Oracle into one of my PC. 
I transfer the files to an ansible control server and use ansible playbook to distribute the files to other remote servers using copy module. 
Finally I write the ansible role to extract and install them locally using the following methods.

CentOS: You can easily use yum to install the rpm package.

Ubuntu: Follow these steps.
https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-manually-install-java-8-on-ubuntu-16-04

It's not quite a good way since you need to transfer the installer to each server.
I too still looking for a way to use script to download from the oracle website directly, but there is no way to do without sign on authentication.

Comment: Great thanks. I also managed to get java 8 operational by downloading the open jdk via ppa then installing with apt get. This does the trick... Sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa; sudo apt-get update: sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -y

Comment: **NB:** Oracle Java JDK is no longer free for commercial use. If you use the above steps on a production server without paying a license fee to Oracle you will be in breach of terms and liable.

Answer (score -4):

You havr to download JDK (Java Devolpment Kit) and install. There is a file of name readme or something like this in text format. Then copy the text and paste. This type of info you can find easily on internet.